# SqlDataAdapter is giving me 0 results

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, datatable, sqldataadapter

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = con;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd = CreateParameterizedQuery();
SqlDataAdapter dap = new SqlDataAdapter();
dap.SelectCommand = cmd;
DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
dap.Fill(tbl);
if (tbl.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    grid.DataSource = tbl;
}
```

The actual SQL Query will produce results in SQL Management Studio. However I am getting 0 Rows of Data. I set a breakpoint at tbl.Rows.Count and I see it's 0 and stepping will skip the necessary code to set the DataSource.

```
    private SqlCommand CreateParameterizedQuery()
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
        string[] allTheseWords;
        if (textBoxAllTheseWords.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            allTheseWords = textBoxAllTheseWords.Text.Split(' ');
            string SQLQuery = "SELECT distinct [databaseName].[dbo].[customerTable].[name], [databaseName].[dbo].[customerTable].[dos], [databaseName].[dbo].[customerTable].[ACC], [databaseName].[dbo].[reportTable].[id], [databaseName].[dbo].[reportTable].[ACC], [databaseName].[dbo].[reportTable].[fullreport] FROM [databaseName].[dbo].[reportTable], [databaseName].[dbo].[customerTable] WHERE ";
            int i = 0;
            foreach (string word in allTheseWords)
            {
                var name = "@word" + (i++).ToString();
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue(name, "'%" + word + "%'");
                SQLQuery = SQLQuery + String.Format(" [databaseName].[dbo].[reportTable].[fullreport] LIKE {0} AND ", name);
            }
            SQLQuery = SQLQuery + " [databaseName].[dbo].[customerTable].[ACC] = [databaseName].[dbo].[reportTable].[ACC]";
            command.CommandText = SQLQuery;
        }
        return command;
    }
```

I am using WinForm with C# on Windows 8.

---

The SQLQuery variable contains this data when debugging

```
SELECT distinct [databaseName].[dbo].[customerTable].[name], [databaseName].[dbo].[customerTable].[dos], [databaseName].[dbo].[customerTable].[ACC], [databaseName].[dbo].[reportTable].[customerID], [databaseName].[dbo].[reportTable].[ACC], [databaseName].[dbo].[reportTable].[fullreport] FROM [databaseName].[dbo].[reportTable], [databaseName].[dbo].[customerTable] WHERE  [databaseName].[dbo].[reportTable].[fullreport] LIKE @word0 AND  [databaseName].[dbo].[customerTable].[ACC] = [databaseName].[dbo].[reportTable].[ACC]
```

debugMySQL is a method that spits out the SQL Query with the parameters substituted

```
    public void debugMySQL()
    {
        string query = command.CommandText;
        foreach (SqlParameter p in command.Parameters)
        {
            query = query.Replace(p.ParameterName, p.Value.ToString());
        }
        textBox1.Text = query;
    }
```

The output looks like

```
SELECT distinct [databaseName].[dbo].[customerTable].[name], [databaseName].[dbo].[customerTable].[dos], [databaseName].[dbo].[customerTable].[ACC], [databaseName].[dbo].[reportTable].[id], [databaseName].[dbo].[reportTable].[ACC], [databaseName].[dbo].[reportTable].[fullreport] FROM [databaseName].[dbo].[reportTable], [databaseName].[dbo].[customerTable] WHERE  [databaseName].[dbo].[reportTable].[fullreport] LIKE '%single%' AND  [databaseName].[dbo].[customerTable].[ACC] = [databaseName].[dbo].[reportTable].[ACC]
```

Comment: Use profiler to look at the real query sent sql server.

Comment: Have you checked the content of `SQLQuery` in the debugger before it is executed? Can you post the full SQL string in your question?

Comment: I corrected some mistakes in your code, but is it what it meant to be? What you really tested?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan how do I use Profiler? I am new to using VS2012.

Comment: Examine this articles [SQL Server Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx), [How To: Use SQL Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650699.aspx).

Comment: I checked the Query and it is exactly as I posted in my question. The same exact query (if run in the SQL Server Management Studio) will produce exactly 1 row of data. Thanks for the tip @HamletHakobyan

Comment: @softwareisfun In SQL Profiler you can find `@word0` parameter value also.

Comment: @hamlet-hakobyan thanks for all your help. I can't figure out how to view the word0 in SQL Profiler. I'm not familiar with those tools. can you post it as an answer so I can give you rep for it

Comment: @softwareisfun "debugMySQL is a method ....." Do you work with `MySQL`?

Answer (score 2):

You can see parametrized query with its argument value using `SQL Profiler`.

[image]

Comment: It says @word0 when I run it